# How Ant script execute command for each file

Tags: ant

I would like to use ant script set readonly for each file in the directory

but `exec` doesn't allow `filelist`:

```
<target name="readonly">
    <exec executable="attrib +r">
        <fileset dir="${reset.root.dir}">
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>      
    </exec>
</target>
```

> The  type doesn't support the
>   nested "fileset" element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [`apply` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) instead of `exec`, it supports `<fileset>`.